# WPF dynamically nested sub-menus

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to build a menu with nested sub menus in the following structure:

```
Menu
sub-menu1 level1
  sub-menu1 level2
      SubItem1
      SubItem2
  sub-menu2 level2
      SubItem3
      SubItem4
sub-menu2 level1
  sub-menu3 level2
      SubItem5
      SubItem6
  sub-menu4 level2
      SubItem7
      SubItem8
```

I tried to follow the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JMS5z_HKIg but it only shows how to build a single level of sub menus.

It is important that the menus will be built dynamically when the application starts because they will be changed under different configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an hierarchical type:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Children { get; } = new List<Node>();
}
```

...and a `Menu` or `TreeView` with an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Menu x:Name="menu">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
</Menu>

<TreeView x:Name="menu">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

...and a collection of hierarchical data to be dislayed:

```
Node root = new Node() { Name = "menu" };
Node submenuLevel1 = new Node() { Name = "sub-menu1 level1" };
root.Children.Add(submenuLevel1);
Node submenuLevel2 = new Node() { Name = "sub-menu1 level2" };
submenuLevel1.Children.Add(submenuLevel2);
Node subitem1 = new Node() { Name = "SubItem1" };
Node subitem2 = new Node() { Name = "SubItem1" };
submenuLevel2.Children.Add(subitem1);
submenuLevel2.Children.Add(subitem2);
//and so on...

menu.ItemsSource = new Node[1] { root };
```